# how to retrieve jbuttons text from groupbutton

Tags: java, swing, prepared-statement, jbutton, buttongroup

I am trying to get the text name of the selected button and send it to my database. Is there a Way for the buttonGroup to pass the text of the selected button name ? as I would like to insert the selected button name into **Transaction table**.

```
 try {
      conn = getConnection(); 
      String Transaction = "INSERT  INTO Transaction"
                + "(Currency_type, currency_Amount,Local_Amount,Rate,Tran_type) VALUES"
                + "(?,?,?,?)";

      pst = conn.prepareStatement(Transaction); // create a statement
      pst.setObject(1,DisplayL.getText()); // set input parameter 1
      pst.setObject(2,txt_select.getText()); // set input parameter 2
      pst.setObject(3,txt_amount.getText()); // set input parameter 1
      pst.setObject(4,txt_rate.getText()); // set input parameter 2
      pst.setObject(5,buttonGroup2); // set input parameter 2

      pst.execute();// execute update statement
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
            try {
                pst.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(connectnm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(connectnm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
```

Expected output

**Transaction**

```
Tran_ID  |Currency_type | currency_Amount|  Local_Amount|   Rate  |Tran_type|
     4   | Euro         |  1200.00       |    1000.00   |   1.120 |**Sell** |
```

Comment: JButton or JToggleButton or JCheckBox or JRadioButton???, depends of, by default plain JButton can't be selected

Comment: How can i select the Jbutton?  i would like to store message that says bough or sold based on the selection of the buttons

Comment: `How can i select the Jbutton` -> by mouse_pressed, Enter and Tab key from keyboard, in those cases is event immediatelly consumed, in compare with JToggleButton / JCheckBox / JRadioButton

Answer (score 1):

```
 ButtonModel btnModel = buttonGroup2.getSelection();
if(btnModel !=null)
{
 btnModel.getActionCommand()
}
```